# React and Tailwind multiple styles with some conditionals

Tags: reactjs, react-props, tailwind-css

I currently have the following set up:

```
<li css={tw`text-center list-none`} css={props.left && tw`text-left`}>
```

However I'm getting the following warning:

```
warning  No duplicate props allowed
```

I've tried a few options to combine the two css props into one however I can't seem to get this working.

```
<li css={props.left ? tw`text-left list-none` : tw`text-center list-none`}>
```

Works, but I don't want to have to repeat adding class names. The idea is all `<li>` have the class names `text-center list-none` but if `props.left` exists then to add `text-left`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<li css={tw`text-center list-none ${props.left ? text-left : null}`}
```

Now, all `<li>` have the classes `text-center list-none` but if `props.left` is true then the `text-left` class is added.